# How to use any state management for my bluetooth app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, steam, flutter-state, flutter-streambuilder

I am trying to use a connected bluetooth device on other pages, but I'm unable to do that. I tried to use the provider, but that did not work, parameter passing did not work either.

After testing, I am using the following

I made a class `ReactiveProvider`

```
class ReactiveProvider(){

 Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> get currentConnectionStream {
    return flutterReactiveBle.connectToAdvertisingDevice(
      id: _foundBleUARTDevices[index].id,
      prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      withServices: [_uartUuid, _uartRx, _uartTx],
    );
  }
}
```

and setup in start

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(providers: [

      StreamProvider<ConnectionStateUpdate>(
        create: (context) => ReactiveProvider().currentConnectionStream,
        initialData: const ConnectionStateUpdate(
            deviceId: "",
            connectionState: DeviceConnectionState.disconnected,
            failure: null),
      )
    ], child: const MainApp()),
  );
}
```

and in `StatefullWidget`

```
final _currentConnectionStream = Provider.of<ConnectionStateUpdate>(context);
```

I got the errors

```
The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

and

```
The method 'listen' isn't defined for the type 'ConnectionStateUpdate'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'listen'.
```

In following function

```
 _connection = _currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {});
```

I want to access the following parameters on another page using any state management

```
final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
  List<DiscoveredDevice> _foundBleUARTDevices = [];
  late StreamSubscription<DiscoveredDevice> _scanStream;
  late Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> _currentConnectionStream;
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate> _connection;
  late QualifiedCharacteristic _txCharacteristic;
  //late QualifiedCharacteristic _rxCharacteristic;
  late Stream<List<int>> _receivedDataStream;
```

These are other functions I am using

```
void onNewReceivedData(List<int> data) {
    _numberOfMessagesReceived += 1;
    _receivedData
        .add("$_numberOfMessagesReceived: ${String.fromCharCodes(data)}");
    if (_receivedData.length > 10) {
      _receivedData.removeAt(0);
    }
 
  }

  void _disconnect() async {
    await _connection.cancel();
    _connected = false;
  }

  void _stopScan() async {
    await _scanStream.cancel();
    _scanning = false;
  }


  void _startScan() async {
 
      _foundBleUARTDevices = [];
      _scanning = true;
      _scanStream = flutterReactiveBle
          .scanForDevices(withServices: [_uartUuid]).listen((device) {
        if (_foundBleUARTDevices.every((element) => element.id != device.id)) {
          _foundBleUARTDevices.add(device);

        }
      }, onError: (Object error) {
        _logTexts = "${_logTexts}ERROR while scanning:$error \n";
      }, onDone: () async {
        await _scanStream.cancel();
        _scanning = false;
      });
 
  }

  void onConnectDevice(index) {
    _currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle.connectToAdvertisingDevice(
      id: _foundBleUARTDevices[index].id,
      prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      withServices: [_uartUuid, _uartRx, _uartTx],
    );
    _logTexts = "";
    _connection = _currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {
      var id = event.deviceId.toString();
      switch (event.connectionState) {
        case DeviceConnectionState.connecting:
          {
            _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Connecting to $id\n";
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.connected:
          {
            _connected = true;
            _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Connected to $id\n";
            _numberOfMessagesReceived = 0;
            _receivedData = [];
            _txCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
                serviceId: _uartUuid,
                characteristicId: _uartTx,
                deviceId: event.deviceId);
            _receivedDataStream =
                flutterReactiveBle.subscribeToCharacteristic(_txCharacteristic);
            _receivedDataStream.listen((data) {
              onNewReceivedData(data);
            }, onError: (dynamic error) {
              _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Error:$error$id\n";
            });
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnecting:
          {
            _connected = false;
            _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Disconnecting from $id\n";
            break;
          }
        case DeviceConnectionState.disconnected:
          {
            _logTexts = "${_logTexts}Disconnected from $id\n";
            break;
          }
      }
    });
  }
```

Another question I have, is how I can use or keep connected using on `void onConnectDevice(index)` function, because as per the provider you don't need to pass the parameters.